# How to get Papa Parse to return data on first render of react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, papaparse

I have inherited an application where a CSV file is parsed and returned to a React component to make graphs.  When I step through the code in the debugger, the component calls the `useTimeSeriesData` function to parse the CSV and ideally returns an object with all the rows. I am finding that it takes two calls to the `useTimeSeriesData` function before it will return the CSV rows and I do not understand why. The previous developer uses `if (csvRows.length === 0) return null` to get the component to re-render so the data comes through the second time (I know using `return null` is bad form, but I am working with what I inherited for now). **Shouldn't I be able to skip this and get the data the first time `useTimeSeriesData` is called?** Because Papaparse works asynchronously, I assume the return statement is being called before the file has finished parsing, thus the state isn't updated in time.

ViewDataChart component:

```
export const ViewDataChart: FC<propTypes> = (props) => {
  const [year, setYear] = useState<string>(null)
  const { csvRows } = useTimeSeriesData()

  console.log({ csvRows })
  console.log('done 1')
 
  if (csvRows.length === 0) return null
  console.log('done 2')
  //renders component with graphs...
}
```

useTimeSeriesData function:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { csvRow, csvType } from '../../types'
import Papa from 'papaparse'

export const useTimeSeriesData = () => {
    const [csvRows, setCsvRows] = useState<csvRow[]>([])
  
    if (csvRows.length === 0) {
      Papa.parse('/crh_viewData_1-1-2021.csv', {
        complete: (a: csvType) => setCsvRows(a.data),
        header: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        download: true
      })
    }
  
    return { csvRows }
}
```

The console log output I get:

```
csvRows: Array(0)
done 1
csvRows: Array(289)
done 1
done 2
```

As you can see in the output, it hits the `if(csvRows.length === 0) return null` line and it re-renders the component with the 289 rows from the CSV. I thought the `complete` option in the `Papa.parse` function was supposed to return results, how to I get it to do so on first pass?